# TypeConverter equivalent in Rails Ecosystem to convert/modify piece of data in post and get operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking for a clean solution to convert Date and DateTime values to local persian date representation in get operations, and whenever a form posted containing persian date values convert it back to Date and DateTime.

The solution in ASP.NET MVC is easy and I've implemented [it](https://github.com/jzinedine/Cedar/blob/master/Cedar.WebPortal.WebMVC4/Converters/DateTimeTypeConverter.cs) in past.

Now I'm looking for Rails equivalent mechanism.

You can see what I've tried so far here([1](https://github.com/jzinedine/leasing/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb), 
[2](https://github.com/jzinedine/leasing/blob/master/app/controllers/customers_controller.rb#L24), [3](https://github.com/jzinedine/leasing/blob/master/app/views/customers/_person_fields.html.erb#L7)) but it's not clean plus that I faced problem traversing association in activerecord because attributes just return the simple members not associations.

Environment:

```
Ruby version              1.9.3-p327 (x86_64-darwin12.2.0)
RubyGems version          1.8.24
Rails version             3.2.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a gem named attribute_normalizer which would be very helpful though that I write my little code block as this in ApplicationHelper and set it as before_filter in controller.

This is a method for converting dates to different formats:
https://github.com/jzinedine/leasing/blob/e495d652f025c344c49dc079f6826e045f6c986b/app/helpers/application_helper.rb